# CSS3/Jquery Bubbles animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this piece on codepen, it is an animation of bubbles floating upwards at random speeds, giving it a realistic feel as if it was in a beer or soda glass.

Basically i would like to use it as a background for a project I am working on. I need to speed them up though, but without making some of them move extremely fast when others are moving relatively slow.

The script uses math.random to generate the speed, because the obviously all need to be a different speeds for a realistic effect, but I cant quite get them to collaborate with each other at a decent speed. here is the code:

```
var $bubbles = $('.bubbles');

function bubbles() {

// Settings
var min_bubble_count = 20, // Minimum number of bubbles
  max_bubble_count = 40, // Maximum number of bubbles
  min_bubble_size = 3, // Smallest possible bubble diameter (px)
  max_bubble_size = 8; // Largest possible bubble diameter (px)

// Calculate a random number of bubbles based on our min/max
var bubbleCount = min_bubble_count + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_bubble_count + 1));

// Create the bubbles
for (var i = 0; i < bubbleCount; i++) {
$bubbles.append('<div class="bubble-container"><div class="bubble"></div></div>');
}

// Now randomise the various bubble elements
$bubbles.find('.bubble-container').each(function(){

// Randomise the bubble positions (0 - 100%)
var pos_rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

// Randomise their size
var size_rand = min_bubble_size + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max_bubble_size + 1));

// Randomise the time they start rising (0-15s)
var delay_rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);

// Randomise their speed (3-8s)
var speed_rand = 3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

// Cache the this selector
var $this = $(this);

// Apply the new styles
$this.css({
  'left' : pos_rand + '%',

  '-webkit-animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',
  '-moz-animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',
  '-ms-animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',
  'animation-duration' : speed_rand + 's',

  '-webkit-animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's',
  '-moz-animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's',
  '-ms-animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's',
  'animation-delay' : delay_rand + 's'
});

$this.children('.bubble').css({
  'width' : size_rand + 'px',
  'height' : size_rand + 'px'
});

});
}

// In case users value their laptop battery life
// Allow them to turn the bubbles off
$('.bubble-toggle').click(function(){
if($bubbles.is(':empty')) {
bubbles();
$bubbles.show();
$(this).text('Bubbles Off');
} else {
$bubbles.fadeOut(function(){
  $(this).empty();
});
$(this).text('Bubbles On');
}

return false;
});

bubbles();
```

here is the CSS:

```
// Sass Mixins

// Animation Mixin

@mixin animate($animation, $duration, $repeat, $easing) {
-webkit-animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
   -moz-animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
    -ms-animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
        animation: $animation $duration $repeat $easing;
}


// Keyframes Mixin
// https://gist.github.com/ericam/1607696

@mixin keyframes($name) {
@-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content; 
}
@-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
@-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
}
@keyframes #{$name} {
    @content;
} 
}


// Main Styles

html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
background: #09f;

@include background-image(linear-gradient(bottom, #09f, #45d1ff));
}



// Bubble Styles

.bubbles {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.bubble-container {  
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

@include animate(bubblerise, 4s, infinite, ease-in);
@include opacity(0);
}

.bubble {  
width: 6px;
height: 6px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);

@include border-radius(10px);
@include animate(bubblewobble, 0.4s, infinite, linear);
}


// Keyframe Animations

@include keyframes(bubblerise) {
0% {    
    bottom: 0;

@include opacity(0);
}
5% {    
    bottom: 0;

@include opacity(1);
}
99% {
    @include opacity(1);
}
100% {    
    bottom: 100%;

@include opacity(0);
}
}


@include keyframes(bubblewobble) {
0% {
    margin-left: 0;
}
50% {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
}
```

So basically I tried to edit this section:

```
// Randomise their speed (3-8s)
var speed_rand = 3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
```

to this:

```
// Randomise their speed (3-8s)
var speed_rand = 2 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 0.5);
```

It speeds the bubbles up, but they start to move together at the same time from the bottom of the page, which makes it look unrealistic and, some are also extremely faster than others.

Comment: If you wanted the speed to between, say 8-12s, I would try `var speed_rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * ((12+ 1) - 8)) + 8);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing 3 -> 0.5, you decreased the speed, but also decreased the variability (actually, made all speeds the same, since `Math.floor(Math.random() * 0.5)` is always zero).  You may want to increase the first value instead:

```
var speed_rand = 0.5 + Math.random() * 2;
                 ^                     ^
           min time: 0.5 sec      variability: add between 0 and 2 sec
```

Comment: that seemed to slow it down more?  here is the link if you want to see it in action http://codepen.io/bh/pen/JBlCc [link](http://codepen.io/bh/pen/JBlCc)

Comment: @JoshWade oh, I see now ... it's a misnomer, the value is actually the time, not the speed ...

Comment: @JoshWade I would remove the `Math.floor`, as that limits the variability of their speeds.  Eg, this seems to work better: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hsepG

Comment: I know this has practically been resolved, but when I implement it on a basic HTML page, it doesn't render? instead there are just square blocks that stick to the bottom of the page. here is my mark up (give it a bash:) )

Comment: its too long to write in this comment box?

Comment: @JoshWade yes, probably ... Code Pen or JS Fiddle maybe?